# R package issues deploying shiny to beta.rstudioconnect.com

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, packrat, feather

I had a shiny app that was deploying without problems on beta.rstudioconnect.com. I added some maps to it and then could no longer get it to work; one of the packages did not appear to be supported. I thought I might be able to get around this by using packrat on my project before deploying. However that didn't work. Now I can't seem to go back to my original version and don't understand where the problem lies. Does any of the following make any sense to anyone? what do I have to do to get back to my original (working) shiny? I had to take some lines out of the output to fit it in here:

```
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 2539...DONE
Deploying bundle: 5321 for application: 2539 ...
Bundle requested R version 3.3.2; using /opt/R/3.3.1/bin/R which has version 3.3.1
2017/02/19 12:05:49.268297412 # Validating R library read / write permissions --------------------------------
2017/02/19 12:05:49.297061610 # Validating packrat installation ----------------------------------------------
2017/02/19 12:05:49.297171083 Installed packrat SHA is: 00bce0ead9f58d31c29e65fb7b87858586356f15
2017/02/19 12:05:49.297294331 Packaged packrat SHA is:  00bce0ead9f58d31c29e65fb7b87858586356f15
2017/02/19 12:05:49.298977087 Packrat is up-to-date.
2017/02/19 12:05:49.299134572 R version: 3.3.1
2017/02/19 12:05:49.299203258 packrat version: 0.4.8.11
2017/02/19 12:05:49.299948491 # Validating packrat cache read / write permissions ----------------------------
2017/02/19 12:05:49.494836685 Audited package hashes with local packrat installation.
2017/02/19 12:05:49.498803369 # Installing required R packages with `packrat::restore()` ---------------------
2017/02/19 12:05:51.169831244 Installing BH (1.62.0-1) ... 
2017/02/19 12:05:51.182200494 Using cached BH.
2017/02/19 12:05:51.182461055   OK (symlinked cache)
2017/02/19 12:05:51.182679371 Installing DBI (0.5-1) ... 
17/02/19 12:05:51.584223157 Installing packrat (0.4.8-1) ... 
2017/02/19 12:05:51.595465126 Using cached packrat.
2017/02/19 12:05:51.595776430   OK (symlinked cache)
...
2017/02/19 12:05:52.163895821 Installing maptools (0.8-39) ... 
2017/02/19 12:05:52.178467525 Using cached maptools.
2017/02/19 12:05:52.178690072   OK (symlinked cache)
2017/02/19 12:05:52.178939945 Installing dplyr (0.5.0) ... 
2017/02/19 12:05:52.200480032 Using cached dplyr.
2017/02/19 12:05:52.200709370   OK (symlinked cache)
2017/02/19 12:05:52.200956042 Installing feather (0.3.1) ... 
2017/02/19 12:06:05.282400309 [1] "Command failed (1)\n\nFailed to run system command:\n\n\t'/opt/R/3.3.1/lib/R/bin/R' --vanilla CMD INSTALL '/tmp/RtmpssUwbS/feather' --library='/opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/app/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.3.1' --install-tests --no-docs --no-multiarch --no-demo \n\nThe command failed with output:\n* installing *source* package 'feather' ...\n** package 'feather' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked\nPlatform is little endian. Good.\n** libs\ng++ -std=c++0x -I/opt/R/3.3.1/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/local/include -I\"/opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/app/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.3.1/Rcpp/include\"   -fpic  -g -O2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o\ng++ -std=c++0x -I/opt/R/3.3.1/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/local/include -I\"/opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/app/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.3.1/Rcpp/include\"   -fpic  -g -O2 -c feather-read.cpp -o feather-read.o\ng++ -std=c++0x -I/opt/R/3.3.1/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/local/include... <truncated>
t/mnt/app/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.3.1/Rcpp/include\"   -fpic  -g -O2 -c feather-types.cpp -o feather-types.o\ng++ -std=c++0x -I/opt/R/3.3.1/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/local/include -I\"/opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/app/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.3.1/Rcpp/include\"   -fpic  -g -O2 -c feather-write.cpp -o feather-write.o\nIn file included from feather/api.h:24:0,\n                 from feather-read.cpp:4:\n./feather/common.h:24:28: error: both 'const' and 'constexpr' cannot be used here\n./feather/common.h:25:28: error: both 'const' and 'constexpr' cannot be used here\nIn file included from feather/api.h:25:0,\n                 from feather-read.cpp:4:\n./feather/io.h:73:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:73:35: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:74:26: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:74:28: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:75:59: error: expected ';' at end of m... <truncated>
ther/io.h:75:61: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:93:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:93:35: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:94:26: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:94:28: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:95:59: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:95:61: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:108:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:108:35: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:109:26: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:109:28: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:110:59: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:110:61: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:150:16: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:150:18: error: 'override' does not name a typ... <truncated>
: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:151:35: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:152:51: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:152:53: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:172:16: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:172:18: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:173:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:173:35: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:174:51: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:174:53: error: 'override' does not name a type\nIn file included from feather/api.h:24:0,\n                 from feather-types.h:2,\n                 from feather-types.cpp:4:\n./feather/common.h:24:28: error: both 'const' and 'constexpr' cannot be used here\n./feather/common.h:25:28: error: both 'const' and 'constexpr' cannot be used here\nIn file included from feather/api.h:25:0,\n   ... <truncated>
er-types.h:2,\n                 from feather-types.cpp:4:\n./feather/io.h:73:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:73:35: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:74:26: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:74:28: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:75:59: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:75:61: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:93:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:93:35: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:94:26: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:94:28: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:95:59: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:95:61: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:108:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:108:35: error: 'override' does not name a type\n.... <truncated>
ror: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:109:28: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:110:59: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:110:61: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:150:16: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:150:18: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:151:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:151:35: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:152:51: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:152:53: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:172:16: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:172:18: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:173:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:173:35: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:174:51: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n... <truncated>
rror: 'override' does not name a type\nIn file included from feather/api.h:24:0,\n                 from feather_types.h:2,\n                 from RcppExports.cpp:4:\n./feather/common.h:24:28: error: both 'const' and 'constexpr' cannot be used here\n./feather/common.h:25:28: error: both 'const' and 'constexpr' cannot be used here\nIn file included from feather/api.h:25:0,\n                 from feather_types.h:2,\n                 from RcppExports.cpp:4:\n./feather/io.h:73:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:73:35: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:74:26: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:74:28: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:75:59: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:75:61: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:93:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:93:35: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./fea... <truncated>
expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:94:28: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:95:59: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:95:61: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:108:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:108:35: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:109:26: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:109:28: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:110:59: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:110:61: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:150:16: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:150:18: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:151:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:151:35: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:152:51: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feathe... <truncated>
verride' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:172:16: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:172:18: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:173:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:173:35: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:174:51: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:174:53: error: 'override' does not name a type\nIn file included from feather/api.h:24:0,\n                 from feather-write.cpp:4:\n./feather/common.h:24:28: error: both 'const' and 'constexpr' cannot be used here\n./feather/common.h:25:28: error: both 'const' and 'constexpr' cannot be used here\nIn file included from feather/api.h:25:0,\n                 from feather-write.cpp:4:\n./feather/io.h:73:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:73:35: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:74:26: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:... <truncated>
 does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:75:59: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:75:61: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:93:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:93:35: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:94:26: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:94:28: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:95:59: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:95:61: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:108:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:108:35: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:109:26: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:109:28: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:110:59: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:110:61: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:150:16: error: exp... <truncated>
er declaration\n./feather/io.h:150:18: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:151:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:151:35: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:152:51: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:152:53: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:172:16: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:172:18: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:173:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:173:35: error: 'override' does not name a type\n./feather/io.h:174:51: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration\n./feather/io.h:174:53: error: 'override' does not name a type\nmake: *** [feather-types.o] Error 1\nmake: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....\nmake: *** [feather-read.o] Error 1\nmake: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1\nmake: *** [feather-write.o] Error 1\nERROR: compilation failed for package 'feather'\n* re... <truncated>
nect/mnt/app/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.3.1/feather'"
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283810404 Error: Command failed (1)
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283822886 
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283836187 Failed to run system command:
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283839368 
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283847263   '/opt/R/3.3.1/lib/R/bin/R' --vanilla CMD INSTALL '/tmp/RtmpssUwbS/feather' --library='/opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/app/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.3.1' --install-tests --no-docs --no-multiarch --no-demo 
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283878906 
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283889984 The command failed with output:
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283899167 * installing *source* package 'feather' ...
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283908105 ** package 'feather' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283911064 Platform is little endian. Good.
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283918990 ** libs
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283921520 g++ -std=c++0x -I/opt/R/3.3.1/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/app/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.3.1/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283944289 g++ -std=c++0x -I/opt/R/3.3.1/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/app/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.3.1/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -c feather-read.cpp -o feather-read.o
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283947838 g++ -std=c++0x -I/opt/R/3.3.1/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/app/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.3.1/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -c feather-types.cpp -o feather-types.o
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283955637 g++ -std=c++0x -I/opt/R/3.3.1/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/app/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.3.1/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -c feather-write.cpp -o feather-write.o
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283958522 In file included from feather/api.h:24:0,
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283967685                  from feather-read.cpp:4:
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283970576 ./feather/common.h:24:28: error: both 'const' and 'constexpr' cannot be used here
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283978363 ./feather/common.h:25:28: error: both 'const' and 'constexpr' cannot be used here
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283981078 In file included from feather/api.h:25:0,
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283989020                  from feather-read.cpp:4:
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283991718 ./feather/io.h:73:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
2017/02/19 12:06:05.283999364 ./feather/io.h:73:35: error: 'override' does not name a type
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284001824 ./feather/io.h:74:26: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284162768 ./feather/io.h:172:18: error: 'override' does not name a type
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284165214 ./feather/io.h:173:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284171921 ./feather/io.h:173:35: error: 'override' does not name a type
2017/02/19 12:06:05.307706691 Warning message:
2017/02/19 12:06:05.307863198 In packrat::restore(overwrite.dirty = TRUE, prompt = FALSE, restart = FALSE) :
2017/02/19 12:06:05.307879290   The most recent snapshot was generated using R version 3.3.2
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284174366 ./feather/io.h:174:51: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284235118 ./feather/io.h:174:53: error: 'override' does not name a type
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284239266 In file included from feather/api.h:24:0,
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284246654                  from feather-types.h:2,
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284249805                  from feather-types.cpp:4:
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284256762 ./feather/common.h:24:28: error: both 'const' and 'constexpr' cannot be used here
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284259715 ./feather/common.h:25:28: error: both 'const' and 'constexpr' cannot be used here
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284266625 In file included from feather/api.h:25:0,
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284268985                  from feather-types.h:2,
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284275396                  from feather-types.cpp:4:
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284277912 ./feather/io.h:73:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284302465 ./feather/io.h:73:35: error: 'override' does not name a type
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284310963 ./feather/io.h:74:26: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284455903 ./feather/io.h:152:53: error: 'override' does not name a type
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284458901 ./feather/io.h:172:16: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284465785 ./feather/io.h:172:18: error: 'override' does not name a type
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284468388 ./feather/io.h:173:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284475582 ./feather/io.h:173:35: error: 'override' does not name a type
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284478069 ./feather/io.h:174:51: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284499196 ./feather/io.h:174:53: error: 'override' does not name a type
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284502459 In file included from feather/api.h:24:0,
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284510402                  from feather_types.h:2,
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284520035                  from RcppExports.cpp:4:
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284528059 ./feather/common.h:24:28: error: both 'const' and 'constexpr' cannot be used here
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284530517 ./feather/common.h:25:28: error: both 'const' and 'constexpr' cannot be used here
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284537373 In file included from feather/api.h:25:0,
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284539717                  from feather_types.h:2,
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284546913                  from RcppExports.cpp:4:
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284549095 ./feather/io.h:73:29: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284555829 ./feather/io.h:73:35: error: 'override' does not name a type
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284558295 ./feather/io.h:74:26: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284565421 ./feather/io.h:74:28: error: 'override' does not name a type
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284568368 ./feather/io.h:75:59: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284699666 ./feather/io.h:152:53: error: 'override' does not name a type
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284702743 ./feather/io.h:172:16: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284709426 ./feather/io.h:172:18: error: 'override' does not name a typ
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284716004 
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284724049 Unable to fully restore the R packages associated with this deployment.
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284726910 Please review the preceding messages to determine which package
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284734403 encountered installation difficulty and the cause of the failure.
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284737341 
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284755686 Some typical reasons for package installation failures:
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284759213   * A system library needed by the R package is not installed.
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284766893     Some of the most common package dependencies are cataloged at:
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284769816     https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps-package-dependencies
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284777079 
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284779889   * The R package requires a newer version of R.
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284795781 
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284799144   * The C/C++ compiler is outdated. This is often true for packages
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284806731     needing C++11 features.
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284810026 
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284817282   * The R package is Windows-only or otherwise unavailable for this
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284820216     operating system.
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284827881 
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284830674   * The package is housed in a private repository that requires
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284837746     authentication to access. For more details on this, see:
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284840342     http://docs.rstudio.com/connect/admin/process-management.html#private-packages
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284848534 
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284851222 The package description and documentation will list system requirements
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284858379 and restrictions.
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284861051 
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284883420 Please contact your RStudio Connect administrator for further help
2017/02/19 12:06:05.284887648 resolving this issue.
Application deployment failed with error: exit status 1\
```